# subprocess.Popen trying to open the module instead of executing it on shell

Tags: python, subprocess

```
action_publisher = subprocess.Popen(
                ["bash", "-c", "/opt/ros/melodic/bin/rostopic pub -r 20 /robot_operation std_msgs/String start"],
                env={'ROS_MASTER_URI': 'http://10.42.0.49:11311\''})
```

I tried to run it shell=True and shell=False. Also calling it with bash or just running my executable and I am always getting an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/ros/melodic/bin/rostopic", line 34, in <module>
    import rostopic
ImportError: No module named rostopic
```

How can I make a call of a shell executable with open through python removing this issue? Tried all combination possible and also other stack proposed solution and still, it tries to import the executable instead of running it on a shell.

Comment: The `env` would shadow all your environment variables; does the tool you run from Bash need e.g. `PYTHONPATH` to be set in its environment?

Comment: The shell doesn't seem to add any value here at all anyway; why do you not simply `subprocess.run(["/opt/ros/melodic/bin/rostopic", "pub", "-r", "20", "/robot_operation", "std_msgs/String", "start"])`?

Comment: Have you tried to run `/opt/ros/melodic/bin/rostopic pub -r 20 /robot_operation std_msgs/String start` directly from CLI? Did it work well? And `bash -c /opt/ros/melodic/bin/rostopic pub -r 20 /robot_operation std_msgs/String start`?

Answer (score 1):

I can identify several problems with your attempt, but I'm not sure I have identified them all.

- You should use `subprocess.check_call` or `subprocess.run` if you just want the subprocess to run, and your Python script to wait for that to complete.  If you need to use raw `subprocess.Popen()`, there are several additional required steps of plumbing which you need to do yourself, which `check_call` or `run` will perform for you if you use these higher-level functions.
- Your use of `env` will *replace* the variables in the environment.  Copy the existing environment instead so you don't clobber useful settings like `PYTHONPATH` etc which may well be preventing the subprocess from finding the library it needs.
- The shell invocation seems superfluous.
- The stray escaped single quote at the end of `'http://10.42.0.49:11311\''` definitely looks wrong.

With that, try this code instead; but please follow up with better diagnostics if this does not yet solve your problem completely.

```py
import subprocess
import os

# ...
env = os.environ.copy()
env['ROS_MASTER_URI'] = 'http://10.42.0.49:11311'
action_publisher = subprocess.run(
    ["/opt/ros/melodic/bin/rostopic", "pub", "-r", "20",
     "/robot_operation", "std_msgs/String", "start"],
    env=env, check=True)
```

If `rostopic` is actually a Python program, a better solution altogether might be to `import` it directly instead.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the code of that file is trying to import the Python module. If you're getting that import error even when you try to execute the file in bash/from a shell, then it has nothing to do with subprocess.Popen.

From the traceback, it looks like it's a Python file itself and it's trying to import that module, which would explain why you see the issue when executing it from a shell.

Did you go through the installation correctly, specifically the environment setup? http://wiki.ros.org/melodic/Installation/Ubuntu#melodic.2FInstallation.2FDebEnvironment.Environment_setup

It sounds like you need to source a particular file to have the correct paths available where the Python module is located so it can be found when you execute the script.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I can see, your `.Popen` command will try to execute

`bash -c /opt/ros/melodic/bin/rostopic pub -r 20 /robot_operation std_msgs/String start`

while `bash -c` has to be followed by a string. Thus, you may need to add single quotes.

Comment: No, the argument to `bash -c` should be exactly one string; and there is nothing in this particular string which requires additional quoting.

Comment: Precisely that may be the problem. `/opt/ros/melodic/bin/rostopic pub -r 20 /robot_operation std_msgs/String start` probably will not be seen as _one string_ unless in quotes. The way you use `bash -c "vi"` and not just `bash -c vi`.

Comment: Bot work fine. In fact you could say `"bash" "-c" "vi"` and that too will work.